# Getting started with Datacell on MonetDB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monetdb

I am a master student working with MonetDB for my thesis. I installed MonetDB and now I need to work with the DataCell extension to proceed. I am on Lubuntu 15.04 and started the MonetDB tutorial, however when I begin to work with the DataCell (https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Extensions/Streams), I keep finding errors.

For example, on the "set optimizer = 'datacell_pipe';" instruction, I get the error "optimizer 'datacell_pipe' unknown". I also tried the "sensor --host=localhost --port=50500 --events=1000 --columns=3 & " command, which is not found.

I am using the July 2015 release, and I installed every package related to the MonetDB on Linux repositories.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

DataCell was officially removed in the `July2015` release, along with the required `datacell_pipe` optimiser. Mostly do the changes in the low-level APIs that its query pipeline relied on. The last release know to work good with DataCell was `Feb2013-SP6`.

There are plans for a port to the new version or a new implementation. Timing might not be great, if you plan to use it for master thesis - it will take a while until a new version is available.